# Reduction of Relative Clauses

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

1-***They denied that they had stolen the money.***

2-They denied stealing the money .

3-They denied having stolen the money .

My textbook says I can use the second sentence instead of the first one . I think I should use the third one because "the action of stealing" happened before they denied it. Or am I wrong ? in the second sentence isn't the "stealing" a present participle  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are a teenager with a bottle of bear talking to your friend in the school backyard, you'll be talking in sentence number 2 style.

If you are a crime novel, you'll have the number 3 all over you.

All three sentences are correct. It all depends on style.

Comment: Thanks ı have 1 more question  in the second sentence isn't the "stealing" a present participle ? or is it a gerund ?

Comment: Again me :) I still have a problem confusing me ,  Sentences (2)(3) is not a reduced form of (1) right ?

Comment: Sentence (2) and (3) not only shorter way of saying it. But also lack a little shade of meaning of the sentence (1). The first sentence shows that the act of stealing happened before the act of denial.

Comment: So to short the sentences we are not using the method that is called "reduction of relative clause" like we use in that example : The man who is sitting next to you is my cousin " to " The man sitting next to you is my cousin."

Comment: These sentences are just a little bit different. You should ask it in the general thread to get the technical terms for it.